# smartsvn : a stored password or passphrase has been requested from the password store

Tags: svn, smartsvn

When I restart Smartsvn on Mac and run 'svn up', it told me 'Enter Master Password. A stored password or passphrase has been requested from the password store' .I have already set 'store-passwords=yes' in ~/.subversion/config, but it doesn't work. So, How Can I avoid being asked this stupid question again and again?

Comment: Ask SmartSVN support.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I found the way to solve it. I realized that the Master Password is not the password for svn and there is no need to set it, so I just remove the Master Password..

Comment: You may post your own answer here and mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the way to solve it. I realized that the Master Password is not the password for svn and there is no need to set it, so I just remove the Master Password.And here is the way I remove the Master Password:

**cd ~/.subversion;**

**mv auth/ authCopy**; (you can also remove it directly with 'rm -rf')

The reason to remove 'auth/' is to clear the password cache.
Then go to the svn work directory, and run '**svn up**'. 
The password for 'xxx' is asked when you first run 'svn up', and what you should do is ignore it with pressing Enter, otherwise the Master Password will be asked when you run 'svn up' later.

Finally, input the username and password for svn by the tips.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

> Open SmartSVN app -> Preference -> Authentication-> select row ->
>   delete master password.

easiest :)